# What is the best type of leather for handmade goods (mostly wallets)

Tags: cutting, leather

I was wondering what properties should be considered before choosing a leather type for wallets creation, based on the following facts:

- The leather should be stitched after cutting;
- The margins of the leather should be polished;
- It is possible to apply a stamp (for branding) on the leather surface;

Comment: Wallets to have a variety of shapes and styles. Were their any in particular or are you just looking for a generalized wallet kind of thing? Thickness can affect your choices etc..

Comment: I haven't think about a specific type, but good point, the thickness is also a good determining factor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hand working there are a few broad categories of leather.

- Vegetable tanned leather: this tends to be fairly thick and hard, usually cowhide. This is the best option for many traditional type leatherworking projects such as knife sheaths, belt pouches etc. It is normally supplied undyed and takes tooling/embossing well and can also be wet formed to hold fairly stiff 3-dimensional shapes.
- Chrome tanned leather: this is what is most commonly found in garments and furniture. It tends to be fairly thin and supple and is usually pre-dyed and behaves similarly to a fairly heavy woven textile. This type doesn't take forming or embossing very well.
- Bookbinding leathers: a middle ground between the above types, includes pig, goat and thin cow hides. Depending on the type it can take tooling

Comment: I do like your answer but I'm still waiting for more answers from people who had experience with this issue.